# Java System.out.println() help. Operator trouble?

Tags: java, console, output

Can someone tell me what they believe to be the output? I dont understand why I'm wrong, to be honest.

```
int a = 9; 
int b = 3; 
int c = 4; 

System.out.println((a+b) + c + " = " + a + b + c); 
System.out.println(a + b + c + " = " + a + (b + c));
```

I thought the outputs would be 124 = 934 and 934 = 97. 
Jcreator says that it is 16 = 934 and 16 = 97. Can someone explain, please?

Comment: Use descriptive title and tags. Your problem is obviously with `+`, not with `System.out.println`, and the “help. Please help :3” part of your title does not add any information. You could use a tag to specify what programming language you are talking about, this would be more helpful.

Comment: sorry its my first time using this so im not familiar.

Answer (score 1):

Let's see:

```
  System.out.println((a+b) + c + " = " + a + b + c);
```

we should execute from *left to right*:

```
  (a + b) + c - the result is int so far and it's 16
```

However when we we add `" = "` the result becomes `String` and *will be* a `String` since that:

```
  (a+b) + c + " = " // String equals to "16 == "
```

Now we're adding to `String`:

```
  (a+b) + c + " = " + a         is "16 = 9"  (note a is treated as a String)
  (a+b) + c + " = " + a + b     is "16 = 93" (note a, b are treated as String)
  (a+b) + c + " = " + a + b + c is "16 = 934" (note a, b, c are treated as String)
```

When having

```
  System.out.println(a + b + c + " = " + a + (b + c));
```

we should *execute first* `(b + c)` and that's `int`: `7` then *continue from left to right*

```
  a + b + c is int == 16
  a + b + c + " = " becomes String == "16 = "
  a + b + c + " = " + a is String == "16 = 9"
  a + b + c + " = " + a + (b + c) is String == "16 = 97" // (b+c) was computed before
```

Comment: thanks so much never considered it that way and it definitely makes sense. thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

With the way you've structured it the you probably won't get the desired result.

Execution occurs from left to right mostly.

See a modified version below .. notice the addition of an empty string in several places to stop numerical computation from taking place and string concatenation instead.

```
System.out.println((a+b) + "" + c + " = " + a + b + c); 
System.out.println(a + "" + b + "" + c + " = " + a + (b + c));
```